# Let $x$ be a real number. To prove...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, recursion

Let $x$ be a real number. Define the sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ recursively by $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=x^n+nx_n$ for $n\ge1$. Prove that, $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(1-\dfrac{x^n}{x_{n+1}}\bigg)=e^{-x}$$

Could not approach the sum. Please help!

Comment: can we use generating function to get a formula for x(n)?

Comment: No restriction as such is given in the question. So, certainly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

We are to prove that, $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(1-\dfrac{x^n}{x_{n+1}}\bigg)=e^{-x}$$

Let's have a look to how the LHS actually looks like. A little manipulation in $x_{n+1}=x^n+nx_n$ would yield,

$$\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(1-\dfrac{x^n}{x_{n+1}}\bigg)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty n\dfrac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}=(1.2.3...)\dfrac{x_1}{x_2}\dfrac{x_2}{x_3}\dfrac{x_3}{x_4}...=(1.2.3...)\dfrac{1}{x_2}\dfrac{x_2}{x_3}\dfrac{x_3}{x_4}...$$

Let $a_n=\dfrac{n!}{x_{n+1}}.$ Note if $a_n^{-1}\to e^{x}$ the rest of the result becomes immediate.

For showing $a_n^{-1}\to e^{x}$ keep obtaining the previous iterations untill $x_1$ by using $x_{n+1}=x^n+nx_n$ as,

$$\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{n!}=\dfrac{x^n+nx_n}{n!}=\dfrac{x^n}{n!}+\dfrac{x_n}{(n-1)!}=\dfrac{x^n}{n!}+\dfrac{x^{n-1}+(n-1)x_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$ etc.

Comment: Very smart solution!! +1

Comment: Could not understand the concluding step to your solution. Please elaborate!

Comment: $\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{n!}=\dfrac{x^n+nx_n}{n!}=\dfrac {x^n}{n!}+\dfrac{x_n}{(n-1)!}=\dfrac{x^n}{n!}+\dfrac{x^{n-1}+(n-1)x_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\dfrac{x^n}{n!}+\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\dfrac{x_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=...=\dfrac{x^n}{n!}+\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+...+\dfrac{x}{1!}+1\to e^x$ as $n\to\infty.$

Comment: oh yes, i get it now! Thanks!